# Pyspark: how to read CSV file with additional lines

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

so I am having the following CSV file. It has some additional strings between the valid rows. Excel seems to do a good job when reading those(and just ignores the additional ones).

[image]

However, the story with spark is a bit different.

[image]

I have set it as `spark.read.csv(path, header=True, multiLine=True, sep='|')`

Is there some simple way to handle it?

Comment: can you simply filter out all rows where is query id starts with `#'?

Comment: u r not showing a full line of input properly.

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-multiline-multiple-line-csv-file/